# pageLoadTimeout not working for firefox with PageObjects

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I using Selenium WebDriver to test a website. I have PageObjects to represent the `LoginPage`, the `HomePage` and the `ManagementPage`. My test first logs in, which returns a `HomePage`, then clicks a button that returns a `ManagementPage`. Then it checks a bunch of stuff, clicks a link back to the `HomePage`, then clicks a logout link.

This all works fine with Chrome, without using a `pageLoadTimeout` at all. However, in Firefox I get a `NoSuchElementException` on when trying to click the logout link. I'm assuming this is because the page hasn't loaded fully when trying to click the logout button. So I put a `driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)` at the start of my test, right after I create the driver. I still get the same error. Changing the timeout to be `5 milliseconds` proves that the timeout is working because the page doesn't load and a `TimeOutException` is thrown.

If I move the `driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)` to the constructor of the `HomePage` then it all works fine though. So I can solve my problem by having the timeout being set for every PageObject.

I would like to be able to only set this once for each driver, which is what I gather it is meant to do from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14606675/1393498). But [this question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/5508) says that the pageLoadTimeout does not work for clicking on links, which confuses me because I does work for me, but only if I set it for each PageObject.

Is there something else I have to do? Or does the timeout get reset when the driver is passed to a PageObject? I can't see how that would be happening as all I do in the constructor is:

```
this.driver = driver;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pageLoadTimeout`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#pageLoadTimeout%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) sets the amount of time to wait for a page load to complete before throwing an error while [`implicitlyWait`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#implicitlyWait%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) specifies the amount of time the driver should wait when searching for an element if it is not immediately present.
Also you don't need to set this values for each page, you need to set them once for each driver.

Comment: Do they always have to be set? My other tests are working without either of them. It's just this one test that doesn't work.

Comment: No you don't have to set it unless anf until you want to change the default value.